Statiq.Web with Handlebars: How to Render Partials Correctly
I am using the Statiq.Web NuGet package to render handlebar templates into a static website.
While I like the idea of Statiq a lot, there is little to no documentation on how to actually use it.
My Statiq pipeline currently looks as follows.
await Bootstrapper
    .Factory
    .CreateDefault(args)
   
    .BuildPipeline("Render home", builder => builder
        .WithInputReadFiles("home.hbs", "Partials/*.hbs")
        .WithProcessModules(
            new RenderHandlebars()
                .WithModel(new MyModel())
                .WithPartial("head", Config.FromContext(c => c.Inputs.First(i => i.Source.Name == "head.hbs").ContentProvider.GetTextReader().ReadToEnd())))
        .WithOutputWriteFiles(".html"))
    
    .RunAsync();

This does work and all the Handlebars features (placeholders and partials) are rendered correctly.
However, it does not feel 100% clean to read the content of the partial with: .ContentProvider.GetTextReader().ReadToEnd()
Is there a way to do this more elegantly?
Additionally, is there a knowledge base where I could find examples to problems like these?
I have so far looked into the following resources, but none of them really helped me.

https://www.statiq.dev/web
https://www.statiq.dev/api/statiq.handlebars/renderhandlebars/
https://github.com/makma/statiq-tutorial/blob/main/Pipelines/FeaturesListingHandlebarsPipeline.cs

